# How to override the location of Ivy's Cache?

Tags: java, ivy

I am using Ivy as part of my continuous integration build system, but I need to override the default location that Ivy's local cache area is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the answer above from skaffman is correct, I found it to be a lot more work than I had expected!

When I added the ivysettings.xml file to the project, I then needed to redefine almost everything, as the default values had been working fine until then.

so, I found out how to add the new cache directory to the in-line command-line within my NAnt script...

```
< exec program="java" commandline="... ... -jar ${ivy.jar} -cache ${project.cache} ... ... />
```

(Where `${ivy.jar}` is the location of my .jar file and `${project.cache}` is the new location set earlier in the script where I want the cache area to use.)

This means that I don't need the ivysettings.xml file, and I can revert everything back to using the default resolvers, etc.

Comment: You can get the default behaviours back by adding `<include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml"/>` after the caches line in the ivysettings file.

Answer (score 19):

Something like this in `ivysettings.xml`:

```
<ivysettings>
    <caches defaultCacheDir="/path/to/my/cache/dir"/>
</ivysettings>
```

See documentation at http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/caches.html

Comment: Ah, maybe that's where I'm going wrong - I don't have an ivysettings.xml file!

How does Ivy pick up the usage of this file? I presume I pass it in through a commandline parameter?

Comment: Found this online... http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html

I think this answers my second question!

Answer (score 13):

I'm use Jenkins as CI build system, and create $HOME/.ivy2/ivysettings.xml：

```
<ivysettings>
    <properties environment="env" />
    <caches defaultCacheDir="${env.WORKSPACE}/.ivy2/cache" />
</ivysettings>
```

This create the ivy cache dir at each jenkins job's workspace.