# Why doesn't SBT download my own libraryDependencies?

Tags: sbt

I'm setting up the dependencies for my first Scala project using SBT.

This is my `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "MyProj"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jgit" % "org.eclipse.jgit" % "2.0.0.201206130900-r"
```

When I run `update` inside the interactive mode, it updates something from `org.scala-lang...` but it never downloads my dependencies. How do I get it to install/download dependencies?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some of the common repositories [are already predefined](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Resolvers), but it looks like your library is not in them, so you have to add the Eclipse repository to the list of resolvers (add this line to `build.sbt`):

```
resolvers += "jgit-repository" at "http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven"
```

just like you would in maven (with `<repository>...</repository>` record)

Don't forget to `reload` your sbt console and then `update` to fetch the dependency or just start sbt afresh.

Comment: I added that code line, but it still does not even seem to detect my dependencies. It does not mention anything about them?

Comment: @rFactor are you sure, that you've restarted SBT in order to apply new settings?

Comment: Oh, I had to exit and rerun `sbt` :/. My bad.

Comment: Now it seems it downloads the dependencies, but I can't seem to find the files anywhere under my project. Do they go somewhere else? How can I use these dependencies?

Comment: usually, they goes to the `~/.ivy2/cache/` directory, so they can be reused by other projects (in section Managed Dependencies [of sbt wiki](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Library-Dependencies) you may find a full info)

Comment: Okay that is cool, but how can I import it and use it now? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and it has no idea that a dependency like that exists and compilation fails and I'm getting "cannot resolve symbol".

Comment: @rFactor to use them from IntelliJ IDEA use this plugin https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea and look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250318/how-to-create-sbt-project-with-intellij-idea for details

Comment: Can't I install them locally inside my project?

Comment: Yes, [you can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142856/configure-sbts-ivy-cache-directory-per-user-or-system-wide)

Comment: I think I don't want to add that burden to anyone contributing to my project so I guess it's best to manually handle dependencies, Git has submodules anyway.

Comment: @rFactor managed dependencies **are not meant to be done in that way**, they are just enlisted in build file, and every contributer simply issues `update` command and they automatically gets autoresolved -- that's how maven, ivy, lein, sbt and others build tools work. I highly don't recommend you to store dependencies as jar files directly inside your project