# How to change C:\Users\Username32\.sbt\1.0\plugins location for Scala plugin in Windows for Intellij Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-scala

I'd like to have dependencies, loaded by `.sbt` to be stored at some other locations. How can I change the local repository location (`C:\Users\Username32\.sbt`) for `.sbt`? I can't figure out this in Intellij idea settings.

Comment: Check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34045393/2000323 https://stackoverflow.com/a/23876360/2000323 Set JVM parameters for SBT in IDE you can in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | sbt | **VM parameters**.

Comment: that shoud be posted as the official answer; however it was strange for me that it is stll defined as VM properties and not picked up from the specific fields