# Making the SBT cached artifacts local to the workspace in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sbt, ivy

Is there a way (like with Jenkins maven plugin) to set the .ivy2/cache dir
local to the workspace of a sbt job in Jenkins? The motivation is to be able to perform a 'clean' build each time.
If not, is there some other way I can validate that all sbt dependencies are resolved from external repositories during the build, and not from local cache?

Answer (score 0):

For changing default ivy home, take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142856/how-to-configure-ivy-cache-directory-per-user-or-system-wide).
One other possible solution is to add **Execute Shell** step prior to **Build using sbt**:

```
rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache
```

Comment: So I guess there is nothing currently builtin into the sbt plugin itself.
Overriding the default .ivy2/cache location as a system property seems like a good  idea.
The 'rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache' will break parallel jobs, so it is not a solution.

Comment: I agree, overriding is cleaner. Maybe reuse combination of Jenkins env variables 'WORKSPACE', 'BUILD_NUMBER'  when overriding default cache location. Don't forget to cleanup cache directories so they don't pile up.

Comment: From what I've checked (with sbt 1.0.4) the -Divy.home property has no effect on sbt only the -Dsbt.ivy.home which defines the .ivy location for all downloaded artifacts including the sbt and the scala lang itself. It's a pity I will have to download all those heavy dependencies each time when a CI job fires and cleans the workspace.