# default cache directory must be absolute in ivysettings.xml error on Jenkins

Tags: xml, ant, jenkins, build, ivy

I'm having difficulty getting Ivy to cooperate with my Jenkins project. The line of my `ivysettings.xml` file:

```
<caches defaultCacheDir="C:/Users/me/.ivy2/cache"/>
```

works for my local machine, but not when I try to have my Jenkins project access an SVN repository of mine where I have uploaded my local project. The error:

`BUILD FAILED
/data/builds/jenkins/workspace/build.xml:132: impossible to configure ivy:settings with given file: /data/builds/jenkins/workspace/ivysettings.xml : java.text.ParseException: failed to load settings from file:/data/builds/jenkins/workspace/ivysettings.xml: defaultCacheDir must be absolute: C:/Users/me/.ivy2/cache`

I attempted to remedy the situation by instead
[using this answer to create an ivy cache dir at my jenkins workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12649547/2877415), placing

`<properties environment="env" />
    <caches defaultCacheDir="${env.WORKSPACE}/.ivy2/cache" />`

into my `ivysettings.xml` file, but then the problem I was experiencing on Jenkins began happening on my local machine as well giving me the same message:

`BUILD FAILED...
 ...defaultCacheDir must be absolute: ${env.WORKSPACE}/.ivy2/cache`

Comment: Sounds like [IVY-1319](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1319)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to configure the location of the cache relative to the location of the ivysettings file as follows:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <caches defaultCacheDir="${ivy.settings.dir}/cache"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define env variable `WORKSPACE` on your PC

```
setenv WORKSPACE=c:/users/me
```

More clean way is to define env variable like `IVY_CACHE_DIR` both on your PC and in jenkins task and use it in your `ivysettings.xml`