# Jenkins 2.0: Running SBT in a docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, sbt, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
def notifySlack = { String color, String message ->
    slackSend(color: color, message: "${message}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}] (${env.BUILD_URL})")
}

node {
    try {
        notifySlack('#FFFF00', 'STARTED')
        stage('Checkout project') {
            checkout scm
        }
        scalaImage = docker.image('<myNexus>/centos-sbt:2.11.8')
        stage('Test project') {
            docker.withRegistry('<myNexus>', 'jenkins-nexus') {
                scalaImage.inside('-v /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2:/root/.ivy2') { c ->
                    sh 'sbt clean test'
                }
            }
        }
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            stage('Release new version') {
                docker.withRegistry('<myNexus>', 'jenkins-nexus') {
                    scalaImage.inside('-v /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2:/root/.ivy2') { c ->
                        sh 'sbt release'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        notifySlack('#00FF00', 'SUCCESSFUL')
    } catch (e) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
        notifySlack('#FF0000', 'FAILED')
        throw e
    }

}
```

Unfortunately when I reach the `sbt clean test` line I end up with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:427)
    at sbt.IO$.uriToFile(IO.scala:160)
    at sbt.IO$.toFile(IO.scala:135)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.sbt$Classpaths$$bootRepository(Defaults.scala:1942)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1912)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$appRepositories$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1912)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.appRepositories(Defaults.scala:1912)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$58.apply(Defaults.scala:1193)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$58.apply(Defaults.scala:1190)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I run the simple `docker run ...` followed by `docker exec` I get what I want but I would like to work with the defined Jenkins functionality.

So this seems to be an SBT issue. I use version 0.13.16 inside the docker image. From what I understand the classpath contains a query parameter that SBT:

- doesn't like
- doesn't know how to handle
- is illegal

I put no such query parameters myself so I thought that this `.inside` method does that. I checked the `env` in the container and found a single entry `RUN_CHANGES_DISPLAY_URL=<my_ip>/job/scheduler/job/fix-jenkins-pipeline/23/display/redirect?page=changes`. I tried to `unset` it but didn't manage to.

I'm out of ideas and am not really sure I'm in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So after long and tedious searches what finally worked for me is setting explicitly the `.sbt` and `.ivy2` folder like this inside the docker container:

```
sbt -Dsbt.global.base=.sbt -Dsbt.boot.directory=.sbt -Dsbt.ivy.home=.ivy2 clean test
```

That somehow prevents sbt from generating the `?` folder and directly puts the aforementioned folders in the root of the directory checkout.

Comment: Looks like the `?` directory name is caused by https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8193433.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time tracing this down through the code.

It looks like the easiest solution is to just pass `-Duser.home=<path>` to sbt, or to set it in the `SBT_OPTS` environment variable; then all the rest of the directories will be built as if the `<path>` is the user's home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that jenkins is running a specific user inside the container. But overriding it does the trick.

```
withDockerContainer(args: "-u root -v ${HOME}/.sbt:/root/.sbt -v ${HOME}/.ivy2:/root/.ivy2 -e HOME=/root",
            image: 'xyz/sbt:v') {
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting ivys cache directory -> [How to override the location of Ivy's Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293113/how-to-override-the-location-of-ivys-cache)

The problem was that it wasn't set and by default it creates a `?` folder which in return can't be handled by sbt itself.

I created a custom Dockerfile to have more control over sbt.
Here are the steps I executed to solve the issue:

I created a file called `ivysettings.xml` with the following contents:

```
<ivysettings>
    <properties environment="env" />
    <caches defaultCacheDir="/home/jenkins/.ivy2/cache" />
</ivysettings>
```

and a Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN wget -O- "http://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.11.11/scala-2.11.11.tgz" \
    | tar xzf - -C /usr/local --strip-components=1

RUN curl -Ls https://git.io/sbt > /usr/bin/sbt && chmod 0755 /usr/bin/sbt

RUN adduser -u 1000 --disabled-password --gecos "" jenkins

ADD ./files/ivysettings.xml /home/jenkins/.ivy2/ivysettings.xml
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins

USER jenkins

CMD ["sbt"]
```

I then pushed the image to our private docker repository and our pipeline finally works!

Comment: I am not succeeding with this. Can you please share with me examples of your `Jenkinsfile`, `build.sbt` and `ivysettings.xml`. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I see that the there is a `?` folder in the git clone done from Jenkins after execution of the `checkout scm` command in the `Jenkinsfile`. It contains `.ivy2` and `.sbt`. What is this folder supposed to be?

Comment: Normaly the `?` folder would be the folder sbt uses as cache for ivy2 and sbt itself. Using a default sbt installation this folder would be the home directory (`~` or `$HOME`). Since most docker images uses a custom installation the cache path is not set and needs to be configured before.

I will update the question as soon as I get back from work with more information,

Comment: @zaxme I updated my answer. I hope it helps. I am pretty sure there has to be a better/more convenient solution but right now this works.